# How can I get a custom 503 error page to show up in AppHarbor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, nginx, appharbor

I've just set up a "maintenance" mode for my Appharbor web application.  By setting a config variable, the site will redirect users to a custom "down for maintenance" page.  I want this page to be returned with an HTTP 503 status, so the site won't be indexed while it's down.  I'm setting the response code in the action like so:

```
public ActionResult Maintenance()
{
    Response.StatusCode = 503;
    return View();
}
```

This all works the way I want on my local server.  I get my custom view with the 503 status code.  However once I deploy to AppHarbor, I'm getting a plain nginx 503 error page.  Seems nginx may be intercepting the response and returning its own error.  Any ideas on how to get a custom body to show up along with the 503 status?  Here's the raw response I'm seeing:

```
HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable
Server: nginx
Date: Fri, 07 Jun 2013 19:26:09 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 27
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: private

The service is unavailable.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The message `The service is unavailable.` is actually IIS's default HTTP 503 message. The problem is that IIS (not nginx) intercepts and rewrites the response by default.

You can configure this behavior by using the `httpErrors` element in your `web.config` like so:

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough"></httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

Note that configuring this may have security implications for your application. You can read more about configuring `httpErrors` [in this article](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httperrors)